# Freya, Samsung Ativ 9, Display Resolution problems

Tags: release-freya, display, resolution

I just installed Freya on my Samsung Ativ 9 series, and works fine. Though everything looks really small, when I tried to go to settings, displays and change the display resolution it only appears 3200x1800 and can't be changed. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Since elementary OS is built from Ubuntu you might want to check their wiki out.

You can set the resolutions you wish to use in your `xorg.conf` File or via the `xrandr` Command:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Resetting_an_out-of-range_resolution

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "External DVI"
    Modeline        "1280x1024_60.00"  108.88  1280 1360 1496 1712  1024 1025 1028 1060  -HSync +Vsync
    Option          "PreferredMode" "1280x1024_60.00"
EndSection
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "ATI Technologies, Inc. M22 [Radeon Mobility M300]"
    Driver          "ati"
    Option          "Monitor-DVI-0" "External DVI"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Primary Screen"
    Device          "ATI Technologies, Inc. M22 [Radeon Mobility M300]"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth           24
        Modes   "1280x1024" "1024x768" "640x480"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

However, the Xorg configuration is the better choice since it'll most likely be faster on boot.